# Indy9 Get Raw Email header?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy-9

Does Indy9 have any way to get a specific raw email header (say, "Subject" or "From") which still includes the transfer-encoding (ie: has not been mangled by DecodeHeader on older versions of Delphi with poor Unicode support), or would I have to parse the entire email header manually to extract this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, calling `IdMessage1.Headers.Values['Subject']` BEFORE calling `IdMessage1.ProcessHeaders` gives different results than after.

Answer (score 1):

The `TIdMessage.RawHeaders` property is what you are looking for, eg:

```
Subject := IdMessage1.RawHeaders.Values['Subject'];
```

Comment: Nice answer, except RawHeaders is only in Indy10, not Indy9. http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007544.html