# How to delete e-mail messages from POP3 server using Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I would like to delete mails with a certain header or a certain sender with INDY 10 / DELPHI.
I already can query my email account with INDY10. Here is the existing demo code:

```
procedure TForm1.BtnCheckClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  Msg: TIdMessage;
  MailCount: Integer;
begin
  if IdPop31.Connected then
  begin
    MailCount := IdPOP31.CheckMessages;
    lbMailCount.Caption := IntToStr(MailCount);
    lbMailboxSize.Caption := IntToStr(IdPOP31.RetrieveMailBoxSize) + ' Bytes';

    for i := 1 to MailCount do
    begin
      Msg := TIdMessage.Create;
      try
        IdPOP31.RetrieveHeader(i, Msg);
        MailsList.Lines.Add(Msg.Subject + ' from ' + Msg.From.Text);
      finally
        Msg.Free;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958055/indy9-get-raw-email-header

Comment: You have the message number in your `i` iterator, so simply filter messages you want to delete by adding a conditional statement (e.g. `if Msg.Sender.Address = 'somebody@example.com' then`, for sender) and use the [`Delete`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdPOP3_Delete@Integer.html) method. The `Delete` method will mark messages for deletion and when you disconnect from the POP3 server, they'll be physically removed.

Comment: I Copy all the msg to a Class TObjectList, If I delete a Item in the objectlist I want to delete the msg on the inbox  in my pop3

Comment: Then don't forget that you can't `Free` message objects when you'll be using them in your object list. But the principle will be the same, you will still use the [`TIdPOP3.Delete`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdPOP3_Delete@Integer.html) method for this.

Comment: ok  , already these comments enabled my for a solution